# Blurry texture in 3D view

Tags: texturing, 3d-view

I unwrapped the faces and added a texture too them. They appear blurry. I unchecked Mipmaps and Interpolation and changed the filter to box. The 3D view still looks blurry. In my user preferences, Mipmaps is also unchecked.
The render is fine, still sharp. Even though, there are some white outlines on some of the arms and body, might be caused by the blurred 3D texture view.
Could this also be a bug? I recently installed it on Fedora 23.
[image]

Here's an updated better pic:

[image]

I fixed the white outlines, but the image is still blurry.

Comment: Try rendering it. If it is not blurry, it may just be that it appears blurry in the view-port because it is trying to save memory. I don't you Blender internal much though. I would recommend using cycles. You can get about all the same effects in real-time (if you know how) in cycles viewport open GL render that you can in Blender Internal.

Comment: Maybe. Is there a way to change that? I have some thing I have to do that need me to get down to sharp edges.

Comment: Could you upload your .blend file somewhere so I can take a look at it and see if I can find what's wrong? (at the top center of the interface is where you change to cycles from internal. Where it says "Blender Render". If you do change to cycles,  you will need to adjust your materials.)

Comment: Does this work: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y585wvh81yn4srb/Me.blend1?dl=0

It's the same rig that I'm using for my other question.

Comment: I could download, but I need you to pack the textures if you want me to be able to help, because this is a texture related problem. Click "file", "external data", "pack all into .blend", then save, then upload so I can download. Also, you should use **the same** file as you are asking the question about. There can be many variables, and it is more likely I can find the problem if you upload the real file, for this project.

Comment: This should work:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/7n626wdbyvwhnk8/Me.blend?dl=0

Comment: I tried it on my computer, and with the scene you sent me, when I unchecked mipmaps that fixed the problem. Perhaps you need to change the window draw method.  I'm running Mint 17.2, and I found that using Triple Buffer gets it to look the way I want. It may not help though. You may also try scrolling down to the texture draw mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is simply the viewport.
If you render the image it comes out right.

[image]

The problem has to do with the way Blender scales images to fit textures. It could scale them so a tiny pixel would look like a box, but it uses the more conventional method, which is to scale them so that they blur. (zooming in on the texture in the image viewer scales the first way though.) (Blender scales like Gimp does, which works best for *most* things. Put the texture in Gimp and scale to see what I mean.)

To really fix this problem, you must simply scale the texture in a program that doesn't blur it, and use the larger texture instead. I would just zoom in on the image in Blender, take a screenshot, then cut out the texture.

You then get this.

[image]

You can use that image in Blender Internal **or** cycles and it won't be blurry.

Keep in mind, with Blender internal, you must switch to **material** viewport to make the blurring go away, because the solid viewport will not show the texture correctly.

You may have to change the texture, then save and close Blender then re-open to see the change take effect in the viewport.

It should look like this now. (your background will be grey, the white is my theme).
[image]

I hope this fixes it.

Comment: Could I use that image? Also, how should I scale it? I have Paint.NET and RealWorld Paint

Comment: Yes, you may use that image. :) I scaled it with a screen shot after zooming in on Blender (which is "simple scale"), but you can scale it yourself if you want. I think using normal Microsoft Paint would work, but I'm not sure, and I don't know about the applications you mentioned. (also, if this fixes your problem, please accept the answer so others know it has been answered, and if not, please communicate your further problems. I encourage you to try it yourself before you accept the answer though.)